# Angular UIB tooltip on desktop and touch devices,

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I needed to show uib tooltips with following condition :

- On touch devices like tablets and smart phones, the tooltip should appear when the user touches the info icon.
- On desktops etc, the tooltip should appear when the user hovers the pointer on the info icon.

The following is my tooltip directive

```
.directive('infoTooltip', function ($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            tooltip: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.message = scope.tooltip;
            var el = angular.element('<span class="tooltip-common"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" uib-popover={{message}} popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-placement="top" popover-animation="true"></i></span>');
            $compile(el)(scope);
            elem.after(el);
        }
    };
}); /*
    Usage : <ANY info-tooltip data-tooltip="tooltip message">
*/
```

Can anyone help me modify this directive to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself,just need to add more events to the popover-trigger as follows :

```
popover-trigger="mouseenter outsideClick"
```

The "outsideClick" trigger will cause the popover to toggle on click, and hide when anything else is clicked.(from [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover))

Comment: According to the docs, `outsideClick` is a supported event but `click:outsideClick` I don't see.